# Iterator with compareTo java

Tags: java, compare, comparator

As a general concept, say we have a compareTo method which returns 1, 0 or -1.

How is it possible to use an iterator to find out the maximum value in an array, using the compareTo method?

Comment: Take a stab at it and let us know where you run into trouble.

Comment: I'm just an old man trying to get my head around the uses of the compareTo method, thank you for your comment though. I sure wish I was back doing homework @StevenHansen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
Iterator<E> it = collection.iterator;
E max = null;
while(it.hasNext()) {
    if(max == null) {
        max = it.next();
    } else {
        e = it.next();
        if(e.compareTo(max) > 0) {
            max = e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what about e? mustn't it no be initialized?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find the maximum element in an array (without explicitly using the iterator and compareTo), then you can convert your array into a Collection or Stream:

```
Integer[] objectArray = {3,66,4,22,4};
List<Integer> objectList = Arrays.asList(objectArray);
System.out.println(Collections.max(objectList));

int[] primitiveArray = {3,66,4,22,4};
IntStream intStream = Arrays.stream(primitiveArray);
System.out.println(intStream.max().getAsInt());
```

`Collections.max` uses an iterator and compareTo under the hood (as you can see by reading its source code), but the second way doesn't (because it's using primitives).